# Python - Using Python to translate table and column names in string expressions

Tags: python, sql, dax

I have a list of string versions of expressions which are written in Microsoft DAX (Data Analysis Expressions).  The language is a typical querying language.  An example query is below:

```
PATHCONTAINS(
Resource[rep type],
MAXX(FILTER(Resource,Resource[Rep Type]=USERPRINCIPALNAME()),
Resource[Resource_key]))
```

We have a list of new table and column names in a Python dictionary object, and are looking for a method to update these expressions with the correct translation.  Below is the structure for an entry for the "Resource" table in our translation dictionary:

```
{
    "Resource":{
                "table_translation":  "Ressource"
                "columns": {
                            "Rep Type": {"translation":  "type de CDS"}
                            }
                }
}
```

Sample output:

```
PATHCONTAINS(
    Ressource[type de CDS],
    MAXX(FILTER(Ressource,Ressource[type de CDS]=USERPRINCIPALNAME()),
    Ressource[Resource_key]))
```

**Question:  How can I perform the find and replace on these expressions?**

Constraints:

- The column names are not case-sensitive - so you might see "Rep Type" or "rep type" in the expression.
- The same column name appearing in different tables may be translated differently.
- It is possible that a name for a column could be used for a table too.

Comment: It would help if your could provide sample output as well, you say find and replace but what components exactly?